# Is it possible to create a global stored procedure at Sql server level

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, function

I created a query that takes a database backup at certain specified location.
I want to use it as a stored procedure but this should act as a global stored procedure so that whenever this SP is called. Then database backup is taken.

It uses DB_Name() to take database backup of owner database.

Is it possible to create any such SP or Function.

I am using sql server 2005

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**first solution:**

If you create your sp in the master database and mark it as a system object and prefix it with 'sp_' then a single copy will exist that will be shared by all databases.

and **second solution** from msdn:

*Private and global temporary stored procedures, analogous to temporary tables, can be created with the # and ## prefixes added to the procedure name. # denotes a local temporary stored procedure; ## denotes a global temporary stored procedure. These procedures do not exist after SQL Server is shut down.*

an example :

```
    USE master
    CREATE TABLE test (c1 VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT test VALUES('master')
    go
    CREATE PROC sp_test AS
    SELECT * FROM test
    GO

USE northwind
    CREATE TABLE test (c1 VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT test VALUES('northwind')

USE pubs
    CREATE TABLE test(c1 VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT test VALUES('pubs')

USE pubs
    EXEC sp_test --returns 'master'

USE master
    EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_test

USE pubs
    EXEC sp_test --returns 'pubs'

USE northwind
    EXEC sp_test --returns 'northwind'
```

Comment: @masoud thx for help, Can you provide little syntax of how to mark it as a system object

Comment: @masoud: I want persistant global stored procedure. Can you provide syntax for that on creation

Comment: @Shantanu: the first solution is persistant but second is not.

Answer (score 7):

Three steps must be followed to create a "system" stored procedure that is accessible to all databases on the Server, as well as be able to run under the context of the current database when it is called.

1. **Master Database** - The stored procedure should be created in the Master database
2. **Prefix Stored Procedure** - The stored procedure name should be prefixed with **sp_**
3. **Mark SP as System Object** - Call **sp_ms_marksystemobject** to mark custom SP as a system object

Example Code Below

```
--Step 1, Create in master database
USE master
GO

--Step 2, Prefix with sp_ the custom proc
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myCustomSystemProc
AS
BEGIN
   PRINT 'myCustomCode'
END
GO

--Step 3, Mark as system object so proc executes in context of current db
EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'sp_myCustomSystemProc'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 requirement for such stored procedure

1. The stored procedure must be created in the master database.
2. The name of the stored procedure must start with “sp_“.
3. The stored procedure must be marked as a system object.

-- 1. Create the procedure in the master database

```
USE master
GO
```

-- 2. Create the procedure with the prefix sp_

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_[Stored_Procedure_Name]
AS
BEGIN
     -- Insert the logic of your stored procedure here
END
GO
```

-- 3. Mark the stored procedure as a system object

```
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_[Stored_Procedure_Name]
```

Comment: How does this differ from the [existing answer by CodeCowboyOrg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25210932/2112418)